# Unity: Failed to build apk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, sdk, apk

So I've tried everything I could find. It keeps showing the below. I tried replacing the tool folder (C:/Users/(My user name)/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk with a lower version. I tried replacing the entire sdk. I tried uninstalling then re-installing android studios. I really don't know what else to do. Kinda disappointing that I finally finished making an original minigame but can't build it. I've been struggling with this for the past 12 hours sigh. Thanks for your time!

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk. See the Console for details.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-9.0.1\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/dlma1/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:\Programming\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
    at UnityApkBuilder.<init>(UnityApkBuilder.java:212)
    at UnityApkBuilder.main(UnityApkBuilder.java:34)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 11 more
]
stdout[

]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1415655/android-apk-build-failed-error-how-do-i-fix-this.html) it appears that...

> Java 9 removed the sun/misc/BASE64Encoder class.
>
> A workaround is to downgrade to Java 8.

Comment: After doing this, I had to go to Edit > Preferences > External Tools and update my JDK location. Now it works!